# Filling PDF form using Select.Pdf

Tags: pdf, selectpdf

I'm trying to fill out a form using Select.Pdf .NET package. Although I've successfully filled a couple of forms, there is a one, which I can't fill.

Here is the link - https://www.state.sd.us/eforms/secure/eforms/E1830V2-WCFRI.pdf

When I try to set some textbox text and the save it it just remains blank. Maybe someone has experience in both PDF and using Select.Pdf, so you could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF in question uses a document level JavaScript which calls `resetForm();`.

That's where the fields are reset to their default values.

Comment: Do you mean "Clear form" button click handler? Or is  resetForm() called somewhere else like on document closed event or something?

Comment: resetForm() is called in a function which is registered and executed in the document level JavaScript (executed at opening time).

Comment: Thanks! I've finally found it